# Is setting the Main Interface in Xcode necessary for Apple acceptance?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode

My project is in Xcode 4.2, designed for iOS 4.2 and above.
I am not using a Storyboard so in the Summary, both `Main Storyboard` and `Main Interface` are blank.

Will this cause problems with my submission to Apple?

I ask because when I set the Main interface to my primary View Controller, I get this error when I compile: `this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key mainTableView.'`
and I don't know how to resolve it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the ViewController Programming Guide:

"If a main storyboard is declared in this file, then when your app launches, iOS performs the following steps:

It instantiates a window for you.
It loads the main storyboard and instantiates its initial view controller.
It assigns the new view controller to the window’s rootViewController property and then makes the window visible on the screen."

The key word being "if". Therefore I don't think it's necessary.

I have a universal app that started out as an ios3 app and was updated to universal in the past 6 months - I didn't declare any storyboard (I've not used storyboards at all yet) or Main Interface. I simply add my viewcontroller's view to the window in applicationDidFinishLaunching.

When you state that you "set the Main interface to my primary View Controller" did you mean you set the view (not the view controller)? Is this a Xib file? A View Controller won't work, it needs to be a View/Xib.

Comment: I meant that I set the "Main Interface" parameter in Summary to my main View Controller (as listed in the pull-down menu).

Comment: Apple' XCode 4 User Guide states that "Main interface" should be set to the "Main nib file base name" i.e. not a view controller but a view/xib. But your application might not have "Main nib" - like mine, I don't often use nibs I prefer to create everything in code so this gets left empty.

Comment: Yes, that's all that shows in the pulldown menu - You can't enter anything else. The primary question here is, Do I need to set the 'Main Interface' or not?

Comment: You keep saying it's a View Controller when it's not. It's a view/xib. The answer is no you don't have to have anything here, I've shown you from Apple' docs that this is the case and given you real world examples from my experience. Leave it empty if your app works.